# Bayes Probablistic Model

Tags: probability, probability-theory, bayesian, bayes-theorem

> [image]

I understand how to do part a. But how would I go about solving the other parts? I have three different forms of Bayes Theorem and don't know what each part is asking for.

Comment: I have flagged this question as being too broad. It would take a really long answer to answer it fully. However, you can oppose this, by cropping your picture to do one part at a time, once you have your answer to each part. Also, could you chow what you have done? By the looks of it, it is a homework question.

Comment: @simplest_mathematics  This doesn't seem so broad.  All MatheZlatan appears to be asking is "what does each part wants me to find?"

Comment: @GrahamKemp Ik, but Idk how to delete comments lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I understand how to do part a. But how would I go about solving the other parts? I have three different forms of Bayes Theorem and don't know what each part is asking for.

You are being asked to:

b.  Find the marginal probabilities for the health status.  $$\def\P{\mathsf P}\P(D=0), \P(D=1), \P(D=2)$$

c. Find the conditional probabilities for the symptomologies (evidence) given a health status. $$\P(S=0\mid D=0), \P(S=1\mid D=0),\\ \P(S=0\mid D=1), \P(S=1\mid D=1),\\ \P(S=0\mid D=2), \P(S=1\mid D=2).$$

d. Find the conditional probabilities for the health status when given a symptomology.

$$\P(D=0\mid S=0), \P(D=0\mid S=1),\\ \P(D=1\mid S=0), \P(D=1\mid S=1),\\ \P(D=2\mid S=0), \P(D=2\mid S=1).$$